# Get-WmiObject works from ServerA to ServerB but not the vice versa

Tags: rpc, windows-firewall, get-wmiobject

We have serverA and serverB (both are Win2016 with same patch level) and their configuration are very similar. I want to create a PowerShell script to collect all disk information for all server. So in ServerA I run:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -serverB
```

it returns: `Get-WmiObject : No such interface supported`

However when I run it on serverB:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -serverA
```

it works as expected. I checked both server's firewall rule "Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)" both are disabled. If I enabled this rule on serverB, then I can run the get-WmiObject -serverB command successfully.

Although I can continue my work by enable this rule but it doesn't make sense for me. Why I don't need to enable this rule on serverA? I wish I could keep all the server have same config if possible.

Do you know, any rule or config I should check and compare between serverA and serverB?